# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at env.js:1:1)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, environment-variables

this is my first question so please bear with me.
I followed a guide to dynamically edit env variables after building a react project on this link: https://dev.to/eslynn/how-to-dynamically-change-your-react-environment-variables-without-re-building-55el.

It works, but there is an error that's stopping my tests and debugging all the time:

After adding the env.js file to my src folder [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNMx.png), with content [env.js content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJGH2.png),

```
export const env = { ...process.env, ...globalThis['env'] };
```

then adding the script in the index.html file like this: [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLLdW.png).

```
<script src="/env.js"></script>
```

I keep getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIobW.png): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at env.js:1:1)  in the console.
I then click the error to see the problem it shows me the index.html file as follows [index.html from dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zZli.png).

PS: I'm using CRA so I don't have a webpack config file.

- I tried adding type to the script in the index.html but it doesn't change anything.
- I also tried changing the script's "src" attribute to /src/env.js, but no luck as it still shows the same error.
- I tried moving env.js to public folder but, it can't read the "process.env" there as it gives an error of `undefined when reading "process"`.
- I tried changing the place of env.js to root folder next to "src" folder but it still gives the same error.
- I also changed ...globalThis['env'] to ...window['env'], but nothing changed.

Comment: As `env.js` is being loaded as a static asset, you should place it in the public folder as per CRA documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: Thank you, but I did that and changed the src to "%PUBLIC_URL%/env.js" and added the type="module" it gives me a different error: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at env.js:1:20.

Comment: can you show the ```index.html``` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this

replace

```html
<script src="/env.js"></script>
```

with

```html
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/env.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean I should move the env.js file to public folder and change the script tag? I've already done that. However, it still doesn't work, but thanks for answering!

Comment: When you run npm run build, Create React App will substitute %PUBLIC_URL% with a correct absolute path so your project works even if you use client-side routing or host it at a non-root URL.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: and you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@owlpro/react-dotenv for automate add %PUBLIC_URL% to env path

Comment: The last library you recommended seems to be a great option. I'll try it instead of the one that I have right now. Thanks a lot. Can I edit env variables after building my project i.e. after running `npm run build` ?

Comment: yes but after each change must to execute `yarn run react-dotenv` and copy public/env.js to build/env.js or manually make changes to the build/env.js file